# Closing the lid won't suspend my laptop

Tags: 16.04, suspend, shutdown, laptop, lid

I have an ASUS TUF FX505GD, and when I close the lid it won't suspend.

The catch is, the lid worked some days ago and now when I close the lid my computer just bugs, the screen maintains black, the keyboard lights are turned off and the only way to get it back running is to hard shutdown with the power button.

I've tried to restart the settings that suspend the computer after the lid is opened but nothing seems to work, and this is a very special case which I don't found anyone to talk about it.

Comment: Update - I can know suspend my computer if I lock the session in my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the power icon **⏻** in the upper right corner of the desktop on the panel, then click the padlock icon to lock the session. Then closing the lid will suspend the laptop.